# If rows of matrix M are switched, do the singular values of M change?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I have looked for a source on the relationship between elementary matrix row operations and singular values, but I can't find a good, compact set of information.

I'm really only interested in interchanging rows. If two rows switch position in a matrix **M**, will the singular values of **M** change?

My hunch is that they will not, and simple experimentation with matrix calculators backs this up, but I am looking for a proof of this.

Answer (score 3):

Permuting the rows of $M$ gives you $P M$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix.
The singular values of $PM$ are the square roots of the (nonzero) eigenvalues of $(PM)^* PM = M^* P^* P M = M^* M$, so they are the same as the singular values of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Changing rows is the same as multiplying by a permutation (which is a rotation, and perhaps a reflection)in the codomain. That means that the SVD before and after look like
$$
M = U D V^t \\
M' = P U D V^t
$$
In the case where there's no reflection ($det P > 0$), using $PU$ as $U'$, you get an SVD for $M'$. The singular values are evidently the same. I'll elt you handle the case with the negative determinant.

Comment: I don't understand why to treat two signs of $\det P$ separately. Since $P$ is a permutation matrix, it is unitary, $U$ is unitary, so $PU$ is unitary as well, and therefore $M'=(PU)DV^t$ is an SVD of $M'$ no matter what is the nature of the unitary matrix $P$.

Comment: You're completely right. I'm used to the $n \times n$ case, where I generally like for $U$ and $V$ to not be just unitary, but actually rotations (orientation matters for a lot of applications I care about!). So I tend to obsess even when it's not necessary --- thanks for the comment.